# How can I call a number from button press in Android?

Tags: java, android, phone-call

I'm very much a beginner at this and I'm struggling to get this to work.

When button is pressed, I simply want the dialer to open with the specified number automatically inputted.

So far I've tried the following:

```
Button btn_call_us = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_call_us);
       btn_call_us.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:00000000"));
                startActivity(callIntent);

            }
        });
```

I've also tried:

```
Button btn_call_us = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_call_us);
        btn_call_us.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                String phoneno="00000000";

                Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse(phoneno));
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```

I've added the permission ACTION_CALL to the manifest.

Whenever I click the Call button the app force closes.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Post the logcat you get when the app force closes!

Comment: Add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" /> in manifest

Comment: You should definitly learn how to read your logcat, it's much more important to you than just getting the answer to this question.

Comment: As above, still very new to all this. 

I will get the logcat setup. I know I definitely have a lot to learn but thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
String number = "12345678";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +number));
    startActivity(intent);
```

You need to add this Permission to your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Wow! First time using SO and really wasn't expecting such a quick response.

Thank you very much. This worked perfectly.

I made one change and that was ACTION_CALL to ACTION_DIAL so it gives the user the option to back out or confirm the call.

Comment: @Nucleotide I'm glad I could help. Anytime :)

Answer (score 2):

i think you Must add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />` in Manifest.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the dialer to open with the number use `ACTION_DIAL`

```
Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneno));
```

You do not need any permission

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have added the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

tag at a correct level in the AndroidManifest.xml file (outside the
 `<application ... />` tag but within the   `<manifest ... />` tag):

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneno)));
```

Also, add the permission `android.permission.CALL_PHONE` in your `manifest` file.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in the manifest file and it should work fine -

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Answer (score -3):

In your Android Phone Go to: "Setting"->   "InstalledApp"->     "find your app"->    "App Permission"->   "Here allow the "Telephone Permission"
Hope it will help you